# XAMPP 5.6.3 but no PHP 5.6.x

Tags: php, xampp, version

Just downloaded & installed XAMPP 5.6.3 for Win ([apachefriends.org](https://www.apachefriends.org/de/download.html)) because I need PHP >= 5.6. Now `phpinfo()` tells me, I'm running 5.5.9. Am I overlooking something or was XAMPP 5.6.3 indeed (accidentally?) packaged with an older version?

Comment: Why not ask the nice people at ApacheFriends.org?

Comment: Why don't u download it directly from PHP official site...

http://php.net/downloads.php

Comment: Right. Thanks. I'll actually do both.